How to add Debug Run functionalities in monaco editor
We have Run Debug functionalities in our native standalone application and we are trying to develop same into Web Application. We are using monaco editor in our Web Application.
We need to debug line by line code in monaco editor to get the outcome. Anyone have idea to implement Run Debug option in monaco edior?
monaco editor implementation in our application
native standalone application with Run Debug functionalities

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
